# How To translate text on a button in multilingual website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, translate, resx

I am developing an asp.net Website.I have Resource.resx file to translate term of website. every thing is ok and I want to translate text of button to english and persian when I use Text='<%#Resources.Resource.ارسال %>'  for text it doesn't work and does not display text on it.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='<%#Resources.Resource.ارسال %>' Width="94px" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click project -> Add -> Add ASP.NET Folder -> App_GlobalResources
2. Add two resources files to this folder, one for English and another for Persian. I'm using English and French.English is default and the French resource file is called **Resource.fr.resx**.The name is important so make sure you name yours with the Persian culture.

[image: Adding App_GlobalResources to project]

3. Change your button markup to fetch the text from the resource file:

Like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Button1 %>" />
```

4. Override the `InitializeCulture()` method in the code behind and set the culture depending on what type of user is viewing the web application.

Like this:

```
public partial class GlobalizationExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        //Get the language that the client prefers from the browser
        string preferredLanguage = Request.UserLanguages[0];

        //Set the language for the page
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(preferredLanguage);

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(preferredLanguage);
    }
}
```

If the above doesn't help you [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eX5um3zSxjI) is a great video on different ways of applying globalization in ASP.NET.